# Vanity onion address not working properly

Tags: onion-services

I have a hidden service with a normal onion address created by the tor program. I then made a vanity address using Scallion and added this to my Tor configuration as a second hidden service but pointing it to the same server directory, ie they are both showing the same page, which is what I intended.

However, this vanity onion address stops working intermittently, usually it works for a few days and then goes blank, giving an "Unable to connect" error in the Tor browser. I have located the problem to Tor and I can solve the problem by erasing the vanity hidden service, restarting Tor and then manually adding the vanity hostname and private_key again. But I would like a more durable solution. As far as I can see there is nothing suspicious in the Tor logs.

Anyone have any idea as to what can be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

When you say they are pointing to the same server directory, I'm unsure exactly what you mean.

Tor connects to the Hidden Service over a regular TCP/IP port. Are you trying to tell Tor to connect twice to the same port (which the HTTP server is listening on)? that could cause contention issues, although I'm not certain.

Or are you saying that the configuration directory Tor uses to store HS configuration information is the same for both hidden services - that would definitely create issues.

To resolve these, try configuring your HTTP server to listen on two separate ports, and assign one for each hidden service. Also try using two separate Hidden Service Configuration Directories for the two services.

Comment: Tor is using two different hidden service directories (is it even possible to do something else?) and Apache is listening on two different ports. What I meant with the same directory is that both hidden services point to the same /var/www directory.