# Vanity domain suddenly not working

Tags: onion-services, configuration

Before you say it, this is a partial clone of [Vanity onion address not working properly](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/vanity-onion-address-not-working-properly), but bear with me.

Until maybe a month ago, I had one vanity onion address, which worked beautifully.  About 2 weeks ago I added another vanity address, and both were pointing to the same site and working just fine.  I decided to host both sites on the same port to make my life easier in http.conf land.

After struggling with VirtualHosts (Apache configuration is far from my strong suit) I finally had both domains pointing to separate folders with their directories working properly.  Then I closed Tor Browser and opened it again to double-check, and my original vanity domain wouldn't resolve.

Keep in mind, the second domain works just fine, and the original domain still has the same configuration.  I want to know what troubleshooting steps I should take, considering I can't find a guide for this sort of thing.

### Relevant Code

#### torrc

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

DataDirectory C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
DirReqStatistics 0
GeoIPFile C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
HiddenServiceDir C:\xampp\onion\[service1]
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
HiddenServiceDir C:\xampp\onion\[service2]
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

#### http.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName [service2].onion
ServerAlias [service2].onion *.[service2].onion
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/[service2].onion/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName [service1].onion
ServerAlias [service1].onion *.[service1].onion
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/[service1].onion/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Both services have the original (working) `hostname` and `private_key` generated by Scallion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propagation.  That was the issue.

Propagation is a terrible thing to pinpoint, especially when one site loads and another does not.  Simply let Tor Browser sit for 30-60 minutes to ensure that the service is propagated.

Other things that I tried (for future reference):

- Checking that both `torrc` lines are in the same format.
- Checking that both `http.conf` lines are in the same format.
- Checking that the server responds to and correctly logs requests.

  - If the requests for the domain aren't being logged, it's likely an issue with Tor.
- Ensuring a reliable connection (connecting to multiple high-uptime sites).
- Wiping and reinstalling Tor Browser Bundle (may have helped).
- Wiping and reinstalling Apache/XAMPP/nginx/IIS/whatever host (I was ready to do this).
- Rewriting the `hostname` and `private_key` files for all domains with original generated keys and names.
- Testing with autogenerated names (allow Tor to set up the name and hash for you, then visit the site).

Comment: You may want to change from using the Tor browser bundle for hosting hidden services and setup a stand alone install of Tor.